# Is there a method to control an iPhone from a macOS laptop through bluetooth or cable?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, bluetooth, macbook-pro, iphone

I know there is a method to control an iPhone from a Mac if you connect both an iPhone and a Mac to the same WiFi network, as described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205644).

For my case, both devices need to reside in different WiFi networks. What I am looking for is a method to achieve the control with connecting the two machines using bluetooth or cable.

Answer (score 2):

You could just connect the two devices using Ethernet.

Plug a standard Ethernet cable into your Mac (use an Ethernet dongle, if your Mac doesn't have an Ethernet port) - and then connect the other end of that cable into an Ethernet dongle that is plugged into your iPhone.

When you have the network setup and running properly, Switch Control will work as well.

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea previously about iPhone being able to be connected to an ethernet cable with a dongle.

Comment: But I am curious, if Switch Control works when a Mac laptop and an iPhone connects through ethernet cable, why not it should not work if they are directly connected with a standard laptop to iphone cable connection. As far as I know they see each other through their ips which I imagine should be the same case with ethernet connection.